# post_exists stops working in a scheduled event

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I am creating a wordpress plugin that takes an article from one of my wordpress sites and then posts it to different wordpress site. For testing purposes, I want it to pull an article at random and then take that pulled article to create a new article every 30 seconds.

The code below runs fine if there is no scheduled event. In other words, if I replace "create_blog_post" with "activate" it is able to detect other blog posts and will create a post call "this blog article already exists". However, when I put it on a 30 second timer nothing happens.

I have tried other things such as get_page_by_title and that will run with the scheduled event. However, it doesn't detect any blog posts only pages.

```
  //activation of plugin
  register_activation_hook( __FILE__,  'activate'  );
  //deactivation of plugin
  register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__,  'deactivate'  );

    function bgs_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {
        $schedules['every_30_seconds'] = array(
                'interval'  => 30,
                'display'   => __( 'Every 30 Seconds', 'textdomain' )
        );
        return $schedules;
    }
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'bgs_add_cron_recurrence_interval' );

    function activate() {
      if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( '30_second_action' ) ) {
         wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_30_seconds', '30_second_action' );
      }
    }
    add_action('30_second_action', 'create_blog_post');


    function create_blog_post(){
      $jsondata    = file_get_contents('http://blog.hansenlighting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20'); //pulls json data from hansenlighting blog
      $json        = json_decode($jsondata,true); //turns json data into something that php can understand
      $ranNum      = rand(1,10); //generates random number between 1-10
      $blogTitle   = $json[$ranNum][title][rendered];
      $blogContent = $json[$ranNum][content][rendered];

      global $wpdb;

      if ( post_exists($blogTitle) ) {
        $page = array( //creates post content
            'post_title' => 'this blog article already exists',
            'post_content' => 'this is a test post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
        );
        wp_insert_post( $page ); //creates post
      } else {
        $page = array( //creates post content
            'post_title' => $blogTitle,
            'post_content' => $blogContent,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
        );
        wp_insert_post( $page ); //creates post
      }
    }
    function deactivate(){
      //wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
      flush_rewrite_rules(); //may not need this since its not a custom post type
    }
    function uninstall(){
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. I am leaving this here in case anyone else runs into the same issues. Basically, post_exists() wants detecting duplicate posts because I didn't put a file path for it.

I needed to include within the function.

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/post.php';
```